# How to update an object of model in django using update_or_create

Tags: python, django

I want to update an object of a model using update_or_create method. But when I use this, another object is created.
My models.py:

```
class SubmitHobby(models.Model):
    M_id=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mob=models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True,null=True)
    is_approve=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to update `is_approve` field on the basis of M_id (M_id=234).

```
def approve(request):

    context = RequestContext(request)
    name= = request.GET.get('name')
    mid=request.GET.get('M_Id')

    obj=SubmitHobby.objects.update_or_create(M_id=mid)
    obj.is_approve=True
    obj.save()
```

Comment: this did not help me

Comment: Your **update_or_create** method creates a SubmitHobby instance because it doesn't exist. Are your M_ids unique?

Comment: yes M_ids are unique

Comment: Are you sure that's the code you're using?  update_or_create should return a tuple (the object and whether it was updated or created) which would cause your call to obj.is_approve to fail (because tuples don't have that field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to get the object you need,set value you need to change and save it,the object gets updated.

```
obj = modelname.objects.get(pk=<id>)
obj.field=<value>
obj.save()
```

Answer (score 5):

[`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) returns a pair `(model_instance, bool)`. Moreover, you need to provide the fields that should identify existing records as `**kwargs` and the values you want to update as a `dict` to `defaults`:

```
obj, created = SubmitHobby.objects.update_or_create(
    defaults={'is_approve': True}, 
    M_id=mid
)
```

Without `defaults`, you might just as well go with good ole `get_or_create`.

Comment: Just chiming in to say that this was really helpful for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your model doesn't set a primary key so Django sets one for you. Therefore, you can have multiple objects with the same `M_id`. If you want to have unique M_id, I suggest you update your model to:

```
class SubmitHobby(models.Model):
    M_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mob=models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True,null=True)
    is_approve=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```